# how to revert an exact version of a whole package (include doc) from https://texlive.info/tlnet-archive/

Tags: tlmgr

I want to revert an exact package to an older version, for example, I want to reinstall the package `newtx` before v1.71. There aren't any backups on my local PC. I found that an available version in https://texlive.info/tlnet-archive/2021/11/30/tlnet/archive/

```
newtx.doc.r60850.tar.xz 2021-10-23 23:54    960K     
newtx.doc.tar.xz    2021-10-23 23:54    960K     
newtx.r60850.tar.xz 2021-10-23 23:54    5.4M     
newtx.tar.xz    2021-10-23 23:54    5.4M
```

but **how can I install them?**

I know I can use `tlmgr restore newtx 60850` to revert to the 60850 version if I have a backup, but I don't.

I also tried to put `newtx.r60850.tar.xz` and `newtx.doc.r60850` into `C:\texlive\2021\tlpkg\backups` and `tlmgr revert newtx 60850`. However, I found that I can't use `tlmgr update newtx` to update it to the newest version again. I guess that it is because `tlmgr` considers "new" as installing later, not the exact the newer "revision"?

Comment: Can't reproduce the problem. Try `tlmgr restore newtx 62369` or `tlmgr install --reinstall newtx`?

Comment: strange things happened. `tlmgr update` works...maybe I did something wrong before...